# Strange bug when applying np.vectorize to sparsify a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting some very strange behavior when applying np.vectorize to sparsify a matrix. The intended goal was to simply set each entry of the matrix to 0 with probability p for specified p. Here is the minimal working example of the bug.

```
import numpy as np

def sparsify_matrix(A, p):
    (n, d) = np.shape(A)
    sparsify = np.vectorize(lambda t: t if np.random.random() < p else 0)
    return np.reshape(sparsify(A.flatten()), (n, d))

sparsify_matrix(np.random.normal(size = (40, 20)), 0.5)
```

About half the time, this code works the way I expect it to. About half the time, it decides to replace all the entries with integers. The problem becomes even more strange when you crank the probability p down; it appears that the amount of time it spends in the "integer case" is proportional to the probability itself. Does anyone know why this rounding happens?

Comment: Read the full documentation!  Pay attention to how it sets the return dtype (if `otypes` is missing).  Also pay attention to its speed disclaimer.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!